# How to use early terminate in wandb sweep?

Tags: deep-learning, hyperparameters, wandb

I am trying to use wandb sweep to tune the hyperparameter in a model, and also try to use the hyperband early terminate method to accelerate it.

However, I don't understand how this mechanism works by looking up the docs https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/define-sweep-configuration#early_terminate and the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06560.

In this paper, the author propose the concept of "resource". In my opinion, in the wandb setting, the "resource" should be num of training epochs. However, in the configuration of "early terminate", I can only see the parameter of "s", "eta", "min_iter" and "max_iter". And through the explaination of the docs, I do not understand the real meaning of them.

In the github examples, it is tough to see whether the early terminate takes effect, so I hope there will be a simple piece of code to explain how the early terminate works.

I wonder if the logged metric shourld be "valid_acc".  I would be appreciated if anyone can help me understand what early terminate mechanism in wandb sweep actually do, especially the meaning of the parameters, and how to change the training code.

I try to set max_iter 9 and s 1. However, it keeps running and never stops.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question. To clarify the terminology and parameters:

- “s” - Corresponds to the total number of brackets the algorithm can evaluate potentially terminating runs
- “eta” corresponds to the inverse proportion of runs that are discarded at each bracket.
- "min_iter" is the minimum number of iterations that should be run for each configuration.
- "max_iter" is the maximum number of iterations that can be run for each configuration.

By default the `eta` is set to 3. In your case with `max_iter` set to 9, early_termination can be evaluated at the 3rd epoch. (9/3)

Note: Early termination can terminate an existing run before completion. However, the stropping criteria for the ultimate algorithm is determined by the original search strategy. To perform a finite search you can use a grid search with a discrete space (Random search and bayesian search will continuously sample the search space). You can also provide a [run_cap](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/define-sweep-configuration#sweep-configuration-structure) within the sweep configuration. Finally, you can also specify a [count](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/start-sweep-agents#stop-w-and-b-agent) parameter on the agent level.

For a sample piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import wandb
import time

def train_one_epoch(epoch, lr, bs): 
  acc = 0.25 + ((epoch/30) +  (random.random()/10))
  loss = 0.2 + (1 - ((epoch-1)/10 +  random.random()/5))
  return acc, loss

def evaluate_one_epoch(epoch):
  acc = 0.1 + ((epoch/20) +  (random.random()/10))
  loss = 0.25 + (1 - ((epoch-1)/10 +  random.random()/6))
  return acc, loss

def main():
    run = wandb.init()

    lr  =  wandb.config.lr
    bs = wandb.config.batch_size

    for epoch in range(10):
      # Sleep a sufficient amount of time each epoch for early stopping to terminate an ongoing run 
      time.sleep(35) 
      train_acc, train_loss = train_one_epoch(epoch, lr, bs)
      val_acc, val_loss = evaluate_one_epoch(epoch)

      wandb.log({
        'train_acc': train_acc,
        'train_loss': train_loss,
        'val_acc': val_acc,
        'val_loss': val_loss
      })

#  Step 2: Define sweep config
sweep_configuration = {
    'method': 'random',
    'name': 'hyperband_sweep_test',
    'metric': {'goal': 'maximize', 'name': 'val_acc'},
    'parameters':
    {
        'batch_size': {'values': [16, 32, 64]},
        'lr': {'max': 0.1, 'min': 0.0001}
     },
     "early_terminate": {
        "type": "hyperband",
        "eta": 2,
        "min_iter":2
     }
}


# run once to obtain a sweep ID
# sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep=sweep_configuration, project='hyperband_example_project2')

#  Step 4: Call to `wandb.agent` to start a sweep
wandb.agent('<entity>/<project>/<sweep_id>', function=main)
```

You will want to run this with multiple agents simultaneously to observe the early stopping. The `eta` is set to 2, and `min_iter` is set to 2. Therefore bracket points will be at 2,4,8 epochs. At each bracket, half of the configurations can be stopped. (1/eta)